# How do I move a file from the client to the server in SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a file: /home/qq/file.txt

I want to copy it to the following directory: wly3@hills.ccsf.edu:/students/wly3/

The way I do it currently it is with the following code with the terminal not in ssh:

```
scp '/home/qq/file.txt' wly3@hills.ccsf.edu:/students/wly3/
```

How do I accomplish the equivalent while I am logged into the hills.ccsf.edu server via SSH?

For clarification, if I type in

```
ssh wly3@hills.ccsf.edu
```

then type in my password and login, what line(s) of code do I type to get file.txt to the directory /students/wly3/ ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in SSH that does that.

Comment: Your title says you want to send from the server to the client, but the question seems to ask how to send from the client to the server. Which is it?

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. The reason I asked was because sometimes it takes up to two minutes to log in to the server, and sometimes I have to upload a lot of files to various directories to it. ;__;

Comment: I meant what I said in the body. I guess I got the terminology mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `file.txt` in a text editor and copy it to the clipboard. Then in the Terminal window with `SSH` running, type:

```
cat > /students/wly3/file.txt
```

Then paste the clipboard, and type <kbd>Control-d</kbd> to send EOF.

Comment: Well, that works swell enough.